# Beamer Overlay Specifications: How to keep uncovered items in place when using only for subitems?

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

Is there a way in this MWE to keep the first item in place when displaying the subitems?
The idea is that I have several items on the slide that I want to uncover one-by-one, each time elaborating on the item with additional subitems that are supposed to disappear again. I find it distracting when the items change positions.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> xxxx
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<only@2> xyz
            \item<only@2> xyz
            \item<only@2> xyz
            \item<only@2> xyz
        \end{itemize}
        \item<3-> xxx
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\item<visible@2> xyz` so that the space of the subitems is kept? Or maybe a top aligned frame `\begin{frame}[t]` so that the content won't jump?

Comment: I basically want the effect of the top-aligned frame that the content won't jump without the content actually being top-aligned. I do want the space of hidden items to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `overlayarea` of suitable height (change `.5\textheight` to whatever height your items require):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> xxxx
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<only@2> xyz
            \item<only@2> xyz
            \item<only@2> xyz
            \item<only@2> xyz
        \end{itemize}
        \item<3-> xxx
    \end{itemize}
    \end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose I wanted to automate this. Is there a way for me to dynamically adjust the size of the overlayarea to the size of the content within it?

Comment: The automatic solution is called top aligned frame :)

Comment: I see. So there is no solution to have the content centered on the slide and still have it behave like it's top-aligned or placed within an overlayarea.